# Subtle hint to jshint not brute force

Tags: javascript, jshint

I sometimes get the complaint that `'variable' is defined but never used.`

I get around this by adding the following in the offending file:

```
/*jshint unused:false*/
```

That stops the error but it's a pretty blunt instrument. What I'd really like to do is allow a particular variable to be unused but that other variables are still held to the standard. This allows me to explicitly exclude errors which I've contextualised but still get warnings when a new possible issue surfaces.

Is there any way to do this?

---

Here's a simple example of where I recently felt the rule should be ignored by exception:

```
var sources = [
    {
        id: '1', 
        url: function(sign) { return 'http://some.url.com/page?c='+ sign; },
    },
    {
        id: '2', 
        url: function(sign) { return 'http://some.other.url.com/'; }
    },
    {
        id: '3', 
        url: function(sign) { return 'http://yet.one.more.com/foo-' + sign + '/'; }
    }
]
```

Yes I could get away with removing the `sign` parameter in the second configuration but I'd prefer to be consistent and therefore be explicit about the signature of the configuration. Anyway, just meant to illustrate that there are some use-cases out there and rather than taking the over-dramatic step of just disabling the warning (per file) I'd prefer to just disable to by variable ... if possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want only some *particular* variables to be able to silently remain unused? There may be a better approach to your problem.

Comment: Sure. The idea is I'd like to be warned by default but when an exception is encountered not to throw the baby out with baby out with the bathwater by turning these warnings off entirely (as seems to be the predominant suggestion i've seen posted on SO and elsewhere). The most recent example of an exception that ran into is passing a function as part of a configuration. The function signature passes in a variable but in some configuration cases the param isn't used. It's true that I could change the function signature to exclude the param if not used but this feels less clean than consistency.

Comment: Added the example to the question but please lets not get caught up on the use-case the point is more to make the smallest possible exception to the rule rather than just turning the warning off when you run into a use-case you want to bless.

Comment: You could use "exported" directive to avoid the warning about unused variable. But I see no point in the example above, you can remove the unused argument just as easy.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, please don't worry about the example. Do a google search and you'll find that lots of people feel the need to exclude this recommendation and I'm just trying to find a half-way step. Can you provide the "exported" syntax you're talking about? Is this a JSHint thing or are you referring to actual JS code changes (which I'd prefer not to be making)